# npm install fails angular 4

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

i'am trying to install dependencies to my project, but when i run the command

> npm install

this give me an error, this is the error

> npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of
>   Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/ npm WARN
>   deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead npm ERR! code
>   ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for
>   @agm/core@^5.0.0-beta.1 npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of
>   your dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package version
>   that doesn't exist. npm ERR! notarget npm ERR! notarget It was
>   specified as a dependency of 'cubic-demo' npm ERR! notarget

my package.json is the next:

```
{

  "name": "cubic-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.2.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.35",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.23.7",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-io-slimscroll": "^2.3.3",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-lightbox": "^1.1.5",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-animator": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.1",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^3.2.0",
    "ng-loading-spinner": "^1.0.3",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "ng2-popup": "^0.4.0",
    "ng2-ui-switch": "^1.0.2",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "1.1.3",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.5.3",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.8",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.1",
    "peity": "^3.2.1",
    "raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "nodemailer": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.4.7",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you get this version number for `@agm/core` from?  If this is the same package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/core?activeTab=versions), that version `5.0.0-beta.1` makes no sense, considering the current version listed in NPM seems to be `1.0.0-beta.2`....  maybe you wanted `1` rather than `5`?

Answer (score 1):

in command line CD to project directory where package.json file exists, Execute following command

```
npm update
```

then execute following command and should not see any output

```
npm outdated
```

if still did not work, execute following commands

```
npm install nodemailer@latest
npm install uuid@latest
```